# How to hide element even from HTML source code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

In a webpage that I am building I am using *AngularJS* `ng-hide` to show-hide an element(basically a button). But what it actually does is simply add a class `ng-hide` to that element.

So anybody can go to developer tools and remove the class `ng-hide` and the button will be visible. I know using jQuery I can completely `remove` the element from HTML but is there a way to do that in angular?

Before it looks like this:

```
<button ng-hide="hide">Button</button>
```

And after hiding it looks like:

```
<button class="ng-hide">Button</Button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [`ngIf`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf).

> The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

```
<label>Click me: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-init="checked=true" /></label><br/>
Show when checked:
<span ng-if="checked" class="animate-if">
  This is removed when the checkbox is unchecked.
</span>
```

Comment: Never knew `ng-if` actually removes the element from DOM. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
angular.element("button").remove();
```